# Custom ListView with Asynctask not working in Fragment

Tags: android

My Fragment is not showing custom listview data. Asynctask is working properly but after sometime application is crashing with null pointer exception.

My fragment class code :

```
package com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.Fragment;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.R;
import com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.data.FeedItem;
import com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.network.VolleySigleton;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentBoxOffice extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private VolleySigleton volleySigleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private static final String TAG = FragmentBoxOffice.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://androidlime.com/wp-json/posts";
    private FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentBoxOffice newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentBoxOffice fragment = new FragmentBoxOffice();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public FragmentBoxOffice() {
        // Required empty public constructor
        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_box_office, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentList);
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute(URL_FEED);
        return view;
    }
    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            for(String url : urls){
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject titleObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = titleObj.getString("title");
                        feedItem.setStatus(title);
                        Log.i("arif", title);
                        //DATE
                        String date = titleObj.getString("date");
                        feedItem.setTimeStamp(date);
                        Log.i("arif", date);

                        //Author Name
                        JSONObject author = titleObj.getJSONObject("author");
                        String name = author.getString("name");
                        feedItem.setName(name);
                        Log.i("arif", name);

                        //Author Profile Pic
                        String profilePic = author.getString("avatar");
                        feedItem.setProfilePic(profilePic);
                        Log.i("arif", profilePic);

                        //Post thumbnail
                        JSONObject thumnailObj = titleObj.getJSONObject("featured_image");
                        String thumbnail = thumnailObj.getString("guid");
                        feedItem.setThumnail(thumbnail);
                        Log.i("arif", thumbnail);
                        feedItems.add(feedItem);
                    }
                    return true;

                    //------------------>>
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("arif", "Parse Exception");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("arif", "Parse Exception");
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();

            listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.feed_item,feedItems);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            if(result == false)
               Log.i("arif","unable to featch data");

        }
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

My Custom Adapter Class:

```
    package com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.adapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.R;
import com.example.y34h1a.androidlime.data.FeedItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FeedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedItem> {
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public FeedListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        super(context, resource, feedItems);
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        Resource = resource;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.feed_item,null);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
            holder.time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            holder.url = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
            holder.profilePic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbernail);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

            v.setTag(holder);

        holder.name.setText(feedItems.get(position).getName());
        holder.status.setText(feedItems.get(position).getStatus());
        holder.time.setText(feedItems.get(position).getTimeStamp());
        holder.url.setText(feedItems.get(position).getUrl());
        holder.profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        holder.profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample);
        return v;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView status;
        public TextView url;
        public TextView time;
        public ImageView profilePic;
        public ImageView thumbnail;

    }
}
```

The line where error showing is :

`View v = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.feed_item,null);'`

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of `(Activity)getContext()`

Comment: you are getting context in your constructor, use that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I think your error is more like `ClassCastException`, don't know why it's NPE, because

```
listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.feed_item,feedItems);
```

You pass a `ApplicationContext` then cast it to a `Activity`

```
v = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.feed_item,null);
```

Try this may works: 
in `onPostExecute`:

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
   listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.feed_item,feedItems);
   listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

in `getView`:

```
v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
v = (LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);
```

Comment: Ok, then please post you stacktrace :)